# Access a custom property in a custom class

Tags: apache-flex

I guess I have a newbie question, but I couldn't work it out yet...

```
package components {

    public class templateSelection extends VBox {

        static public var tempSelectionBag:Dictionary;

        public function templateSelection() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have a custom class tempSelection with a Dictionary as a public accessable property of that class. If I use this code, the compiler tells me:

> 1046: Typ wurde nicht gefunden oder
>   war keine
>   Kompilierungszeit-Konstante:Dictionary

Which translates to:

> Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: `Dictionary`

Any help is appreciated!

Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message in English:

> Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: `Dictionary`

To fix it, import the `Dictionary` class into your program:

```
package components 
{
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    .
    .
```